# Htaccess FilesMatch Allow and Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

This is what I have in my htaccess file now and it's working well, but I want to change it so that traffic which is denied gets forwarded to another url. Is this possible?

```
<FilesMatch ^((sitemapfile|otherfile)\.php$)$>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 69.16.233.219
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the ErrorDocument 403 (forbidden) to redirect to whatever you need to, in your .htaccess file or apache config.

Example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
```

or if you need to redirect to a path relative to the domain

```
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden
```

Please bear in mind that this will redirect the users for any 403 that occurs on the site, so use it carefully.